# Can we load, display and manipulate image's matrix without using any library in c++?

Tags: c++, image, visual-c++, image-processing

is it possible to do changes to image's matrix without using any library in c++? to load and display image as well?

Comment: Define what you call an image, and what you mean by displaying it. Purely standard C++ does not have any notion of images.

Comment: What image format and changes, precisely? This question is quite broad, almost to the point of being ambiguous.

Comment: i wanted to manipulate jpeg type image, without using extra libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Grab a copy of the specification for whatever image format you're interested and write the read/write functions yourself.

Note that to write display functionality without an external library you'll likely need to run your code in kernel mode to get to the frame buffer memory, but that can certainly be done.

Not that you'd necessarily want to do it that way...

Comment: Strictly speaking, "without using *any* library" would exclude the standard library as well, so how would you open a file then?

Answer (score 1):

Like any typical file, an image file is simply made up of bytes; there is nothing special about an image file.

In my opinion, the most difficult part of reading/writing image files without the use of a library is understanding the file format. Once you understand the format, all you need to do is define appropriate data structures and read the image data into them (for more advanced formats you may have to do some extra work e.g. decompression).

The simplest image format to work with would have to be PPM. It's a pretty bad format but it's nice and easy to read in and write back to a file.
http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html

Apart from that, bitmaps are also pretty simple to work with. Like Drew said, just download a copy of the specification and work from there.

As for displaying images, I think you're best off using a library or framework unless you want to see how it's done for the sake of learning.